# Mempool amd memcheck inplementation in C

Tags: c, linux, data-structures

**Is there a way to reuse de-allocate memory from a mempool **

i want to free certain block of used memory and want to give it back to mempool again.

I have allocated a certain amount of memory upfront and use that memory for the rest of the program. The program will basically be allocating memory for a  structure.

for example  i have created  100Kb of memory allocation initially, after that i want to use that memory in chunk of 30Kb.

***How can i implement "memcheck" which check corrupted memory through out mempool.***

i have created mempool like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

typedef struct POOL
{

```
    char *next;
    char *end;
```

}pool;

pool *pool_create (size_t size)
{

```
    pool *p = (pool*)malloc (size + sizeof (pool));
    p->next = (char*)&p[1];
    p->end  = p->next + size;

    return p;
```

}

void pool_destroy (pool *p) {

```
    free (p);
    p = NULL;
```

}

size_t pool_available (pool *p) {

```
    return p->end - p->next;
```

}

void *pool_alloc (pool *p, size_t size) {

```
    if (pool_available(p) < size) {
            printf ("oops!!! No memory left in mempool\n");
            return NULL;
    }
    void *mem = (void *)p->next;
    p->next +=size;
    printf ("memeory successfully allocated from pool\n");
    return mem;
```

}

int main () {

```
    pool *my_pool = pool_create (100);
    pool *use1,*use2,*use3,*use4;

    printf ("pool_available is %d\n\n",pool_available(my_pool));

    use1 = pool_alloc (my_pool, 30);
    printf ("pool_available is %d\n\n",pool_available(my_pool));

    use2 = pool_alloc (my_pool, 30);
    printf ("pool_available is %d\n\n",pool_available(my_pool));

    use3 = pool_alloc (my_pool, 30);
    printf ("pool_available is %d\n\n",pool_available(my_pool));

    use4 = pool_alloc (my_pool, 50);
    printf ("pool_available is %d\n\n",pool_available(my_pool));

    return 0;
```

}

in this code i want to free use2 memory block and wnat to resue that memory again.

now total memory in mempool is 10. after freeing use2, total memory will be 40. so how can i safely free use2 and use this block again in mempool.

Comment: "new" - are you talking about C++?

Comment: mempool is a standard component of many c++ libraries.  {POCO}(http://pocoproject.org/docs/) for instance has one under core/mempool and I am sure Boost has something similar.  If you insist on doing it yourself google malloc and read how versions manage their free lists and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have an equivalent pool_dealloc (or pool_free however to want to call it) function that will free a chunk of the pools storage through a pointer to it's beginning. The freeing of the area will not be literally a call to free but you would have to add the area to a list of free chunks/areas so that it could be reused by pool_alloc.  Now the implementation above is pretty naive in the sense that you cannot implement a pool allocator without additional data structures that will take care of keeping track of chunks sizes etc. and free/occupied blocks so I suggest that you read about how various allocators are implemented and try to understand the intricacies you should be able o find a lot of information. In general it is not as easy as the way you show above especially if you want a robust and scalable solution. If you want to do it the above way you would need to keep a free list of pointers and sizes and manipulate it accordingly.